# Can't download or copy SVG without body element

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, clipboard

How do I successfully copy to clipboard the SVG content on this page?

https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-icon-e94956d5f010d19607348176b0ae90def55d61871a43cb4bcb6d771d8d235471.svg

I get an error at the `select()` method that looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.select is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:4
```

This is my code at the moment that can be run in the console.

```
function copyClip() {
  const docEl = document.documentElement
  const string = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(docEl)
  const el = document.createElement('textarea')
  docEl.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', el)
  el.value = string
  el.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}

copyClip()
```

Comment: how would you like to be answered if you also give a little information? PLEASE READ : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One answer to this is to use a different execution of copying to clipboard but I don't understand why the `select` method in the original question isn't working. This function works:

```
const docEl = document.documentElement
    const string = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(docEl)
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(string).then(
      function () {
        alert('The SVG was copied to your clipboard.')
      },
      function (err) {
        alert('Could not copy:', err)
      }
    )
```